# Where are the strings causing my error in this df?

Tags: python, pandas

This mre gives throws  `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

```
ActualClose = [898,1415,226,6006 ]  
Predicted = [905,1426,229,6021]
Prior = [891,1351,228,5993]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ActualClose, Predicted, Prior)), columns =['Actual', 'Predicted', "Prior"])
count = 0
for row in df:
    if row['Actual'] & row['Predicted'] > row['Prior'] | row['Actual'] & row['Predicted'] < row['Prior']:
        count = count + 1
```

I don't understand where the strings are that would be interferring with running my logic, can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: `for row in df:` iterates the dataframe's column names.

Comment: One of the goals of pandas is to have operations that are applied to entire columns fo data. Iterating rows is less efficient. Better to see if you can use the dataframe's logical operations or ufuncs and demonstrated below.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this one-liner instead:

```
count = ((df['Actual'] & df['Predicted'] > df['Prior']) | df['Actual'] & (df['Predicted'] < df['Prior'])).sum()
```

And now:

```
print(count)
```

Would give:

```
2
```

Comment: _ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()._ What you are doing is great but needs some tweaking.

Comment: @tdelaney Ah messed those parenthesizes up a bit... edited my answer! thanks for the catch :P

Answer (score 0):

I think to iterate throw each row of a dataframe, you should use `df.iterrows()` instead of `df`

```
ActualClose = [898,1415,226,6006 ]  
Predicted = [905,1426,229,6021]
Prior = [891,1351,228,5993]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ActualClose, Predicted, Prior)), columns =['Actual', 'Predicted', "Prior"])
count = 0
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Actual'] & row['Predicted'] > row['Prior'] | row['Actual'] & row['Predicted'] < row['Prior']:
        count = count + 1
```